# TColor Initialise with int works with {} but not ()

Tags: c++, c++17, c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I'm using Embarcader C++Builder 10.4.2 with the Clang32 compiler in the IDE to build a VCL Windows 32-bit app.

I used to use `()` initializers for my own `TColor` constants when I used the old "Classic" compiler. But the Clang32 compiler doesn't accept this. The Clang32 does accept the same initialize value, but with the C++ 17 (and earlier I think) `{}` intializers.

Thanks Remy for advice: I should have included error message in my original posting. The error message reported by the Clang32 compiler is:

> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(15, 13):  cannot initialize a variable of type 'const System::Uitypes::TColor' with an rvalue of type 'int'

I don't understand why Clang32 doesn't like the `()` initializer syntax. Can anyone explain please?

Code example attached:

```cpp
#include <vcl.h>

const TColor MeterBarBezelRimColour{0x00DDDDDD};   // works with Clang32 - (too "modern" for Classic compiler)
    
const TColor AnotherBezelRimColour(0x00CCCCCC);    // give an error with Clang32 (but does work for Classic compiler).

// WHY is this not accepted by Clang?
```

Comment: "give an error" What error?? [Edit] to quote it in full.

Comment: I would say that the "Classic compiler" were wrong to accept `()`. Does `TColor` has constructor, or is it an aggregate?

Comment: @underscore_d - I searched through the header files and found: enum DECLSPEC_DENUM TColor : int {clMin=-0x7fffffff-1, clMax=0x7fffffff}; I then needed to know what the DECLSPEC_DENUM was. I found where this macro is defined (in sysmac.h and I believe that for clang32 DECLSPEC_DENUM is defined as an empty value, which makes TColor a simple enum.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I think it very likely that the "Classic" compiler is wrong. But I don't understand why and hope someone can explain.

Comment: As you found definition of `TColor`, you might reduce your example (`#include <vcl.h>` is really specific) to `enum EMyEnum : int {A=0, B=0xFF}; const EMyEnum e1(42), e2{42};` (is that short example still fail? if yes, easier for us to reproduce/answer. if no, then you have to investigate more (is `DECLSPEC_DENUM` has different definition depending of compiler?..)).

Comment: @Jarod42 - good idea of yours. Including vcl.h does ensure that helpful people such as yourself know I'm on the Embarcadero vcl system - but yes, the question is not expected to be related to vcl. I've done exactly as you suggest. EMyEnum gives exactly the same error message in a (very short) cpp file with no #include statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) doesn't allow an `enum` to be initialized from `int` with `(..)`.

And since C++17:

[list_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation) allows an `enum` to be initialized from `int` with `{..}`:

> Otherwise, if T is a enumeration type that is either scoped or unscoped with fixed underlying type, and if the braced-init-list has only one initializer, and if the conversion from the initializer to the underlying type is non-narrowing, and if the initialization is direct-list-initialization, then the enumeration is initialized with the result of converting the initializer to its underlying type.

Clang is right to accept `{..}` (since C++17) and reject the `(..)` construct.

Your "Classic" compiler is wrong in that regard (pre-C++17, it should reject both).